# Why 64Bit version app is much slower than 32Bit version

Tags: c++, performance, ubuntu, 32bit-64bit

In order to solve the 3G (Ubuntu) memory issue (sometimes we do need more memory than 3G), I compiled my app under a 64bit environment to use more memory.

But, my 64bit app is much slower than the 32bit version.

32Bit version is built on a 32 bit machine;
64Bit version is build on a 64 bit machine;
both 32Bit and 64Bit versions run on the 64Bit machine in our loading test.

I googled, and some folks said, the unnecessary `long` type can make the 64bit slower than 32bit, because:

```
man g++:

   -m64
       Generate code for a 32-bit or 64-bit environment.  The 32-bit environment
       sets int, long and pointer to 32 bits and generates code that runs on any
       i386 system. The 64-bit environment sets int to 32 bits and long and
       pointer to 64 bits and generates code for AMD's x86-64 architecture. For
       darwin only the -m64 option turns off the -fno-pic and -mdynamic-no-pic
       options.
```

So I changed all my `long`s to `int`s, but still same result.

Please advise.

Peter

Edit:

- About memory, both 32 and 64 versions use similar memory, about 1.5 ~
  2.5 GB, and my machine has 9GB physical memory;
- I profiled using OProfile, and for most of the functions, the 64bit version collects
  more profiling samples than the 32bit version;
- I cannot think of any
  other bottlenecks, please advise.
- My app is a server, and the loading test was done under a 100 client connections.  The server does a lot of computation processing the audio data from the clients.

Comment: Pointers are all twice as wide too. That can make a difference. What does your app do? Have you profiled?

Comment: Do you try the app while its using same memory on 32 bit and 64 bit?

Comment: I suspect that if you are switching architecture because your application exceeds the OS memory capacity there are other bottlenecks that aren't being addressed in your code.

Comment: All my computationally intensive (though small) apps gained 5% to 20% speedup from recompiling to 64 bits. What does your app do?

Comment: @ZanLynx, I think `in`t on stardard x86-64 Linux system is 4 bytes, which is 32 bits, at least on my Ubuntu 11.10 64bit.

Comment: @PeterLee: Ah, you are correct. I will withdraw my comment.

Answer (score 4):

Profile your app. That will tell you where the slow code is.

Comment: I profiled using OProfile, and for most of the functions, the 64bit version collects more profiling samples than the 32bit version.  But I don't know why.

Comment: @PeterLee, it's very unusual for the entire app to slow down all at once, you should see that one or a few functions are taking a larger percentage of the total under 64bit than they were under 32bit.

Answer (score 2):

1. For the question "why", no one will know the reason without details. You must analyze the profiled result and if there are any problem with the result, post it as a question here.
2. If your app does not need more than 4GB of RAM (1.5~2.5GB in your case), you should try [x32](https://sites.google.com/site/x32abi/). It's a new [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI) that allows for 32-bit pointers in 64-bit environment.